# How to add ol.layer.Vector source dynamically?

Tags: openlayers

How to set source dynamically to a layer vector in OpenLayers 3

like this

```
var vectorLayer=  new ol.layer.Vector({  
    source: new ol.source.Vector()
});

vectorLayer.setSource(another_source);
```

Is it possible?

Comment: To complete Sefa answer, you can also get the source doing `var source = vectorLayer.getSource()` and manipulate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no method for setting source at api, http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/apidoc/ol.layer.Vector.html. 
However you can define source;

```
var source = new ol.source.Vector();
```

and set source at the beginning;

```
var vectorLayer=  new ol.layer.Vector({

source: source

});
```

Then you are free to add or remove features to source dynamically by using addFeature and removeFeature methods without a need of dynamic change of source.